# Making duplicate, but differently worded, questions more findable

Tags: discussion

I was tempted to open a question like "How can I make an arrow stick to a graphics primitive?" or something like that, then get it pushed as a duplicate to here: [Framework behind Graph plots. DynamicNamespace and friends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155237/framework-behind-graph-plots-dynamicnamespace-and-friends) My reason for doing this would be to make it easier to find the Q/A if you were coming at it from a very different angle.

On the other hand, I feel like this is probably cluttersome and probably bad practice.

What're good ways to make sure duplicates in everything but phrasing get picked up by search?

Comment: I understand what you're going for, but I do feel queasy at the thought of deliberately posting a dupe question.

Comment: @J.M. Me too. Hence this question.

Comment: You can ask about documented alternatives and link the topic in the question. Won't be closed and makes sense ;)

Comment: Wouldn't be better to edit the original question or answer to add the relevant keywords?

Comment: @rhermans sometimes not without making the original question less effective, I think. By which I mean I wouldn't really want to clutter up an effective question with too many keywords or additions to the title (since for many people, they'll never get past the title). I do like Kuba's idea of asking a similar, but expanded question. It's an effective way to link the original to other things too.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What about a new answer with the broader scope?

Comment: @rhermans That's definitely not a bad idea. It'd solve the search-keywords issue so the answer would at least be found.